# While hitting from Postman i am able to access data without authrization but why not with angular 2 application

Tags: asp.net, angular

I am using a ASP.Net Web API. When i am selecting no authentication while creating web API project the same code works but when i use individual authentication it throws 401 error even after trying all possible tricks. Please help me to handle different authentication modes available in ASP. Net project creation. I did not find any proper document on individual authentication even on MSDN. 
Also suggest me the recommended way to send token or credentials to the web API.

The below written code is of Angular 2 service. `getOneItemDetailsCallClient` is working but `getOneItemDetailsCall` throws 401

```
getOneItemDetailsCall():Observable<any>{
return this.http.get('http://localhost:56265/api/ProductDetail').map((response:Response)=>response.json());
}



getOneItemDetailsCallClient():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts').map((response:Response)=><OneItemComponent[]>response.json());
  }
```

Error details:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:56265/api/ProductDetail
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:56265
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 6161
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 18:04:04 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcdmlwdWxzaW5naFxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDE1XFByb2plY3RzXEZsaXBab25fQmFja2VuZFxGbGlwWm9uX0JhY2tlbmRcYXBpXFByb2R1Y3REZXRhaWw=?=
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:56265
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/OneItem
```

Comment: Some code of the backend would be nice. From the ProductDetail method.

Comment: Backend is very simple code with a controller and few  methods like get, put, post etc. I am trying to call get method which i am able to access from browser or postman both.

Comment: public class ProductDetailController : ApiController
    {public string GetProductDetails()
        {  string query = "select * from Product_Details";Product_Details pd =new Product_Details(); return pd.getProduct(query);}                                                                                      I have written the CORS code as well in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the api from a different domain than the API is hosted so it is blocking your requests. Adding cross origin requests (CORS) should resolve your problem. Here is a link to  [ASP.NET Core CORS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

In Startup.cs You should be able to call:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

But may need to specify your Angular host app as the origin:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

    // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
    app.UseCors(builder =>
       builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Comment: <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <handlers>                                                                                                               I have already added this code for CORS in web.config file

Comment: * symbol is not showing above. Actually it is written like value="*".

Comment: With exactly same code i am able to call get method from my angular application. The only difference is i have selected no authentication instead of individual user account option while creating the project